# JavaScript: call vs call.bind

Tags: javascript

Why does - in the following code - line 3 work and line 4 does not?

```
function out(x) {
  console.log(x);
}
out.call(window, "bla") // outputs "bla"
out.call.bind(window, "bla")(); // throws "TypeError: object is not a function"
```

Comment: You meant to write `out.bind(window, "bla")()`.

Comment: No, I didn't ;) Why can't I bind call?

Comment: Why would you want to bind `call`? What is the desired result?

Comment: why not? just pushing on the boundaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you probably have a typo: you meant to write `out.bind(window, "bla")()` instead, which would produce the same result as the call that works.

Why the error with the current code? Well `out.call.bind` returns a function that fixes the value of `this` within `call` to `window`. However, `call` expects `this` to be a function, which `window` is not. The result is the given error.

From the [annotated ES5 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5):

> #### 15.3.4.5 Function.prototype.bind (thisArg [, arg1 [, arg2, …]])
>
> The bind method takes one or more arguments, thisArg and (optionally)
>   arg1, arg2, etc, and returns a new function object by performing the
>   following steps:
>
> ```
> 1. Let Target be the this value.
> 2. If IsCallable(Target) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> [...]
> ```

You are getting a `TypeError` as expected.

#### Addendum

The `out.call.bind` usage, much like the similar `out.call.call`, results in "redirecting the target" of `out.call` -- that is, instead of `call` being invoked on `out`, it will be invoked on something else. An example:

```
function foo(x) { console.log("this", this, "foo", x); }
function bar(x) { console.log("this", this, "bar", x); }

foo.call.bind(bar, window, 42)();  // "this" [window] "bar" 42
```

Comment: @Tobo: The first argument, `thisArg` is what you want to bind `this` to *when you call the function*. I am talking about the value of `this` *when you call `call`*.